# php refactoring and better coding for php?

Tags: php, mysql, performance, refactoring, code-readability

i have this process that is the heart of my app, that im creating, but for some reason i feel like its the worst way to do it(instinct) , and i wanted to see if thier is something wrong with this process, and am i approaching it in a bad way! p.s. the code works fine, just refactoring problem.

the process is:

users go to homepage, they see thier latest activities, by other site memebers(home.php),

```
 //function to bring the latest activities from database
   $results=function getUserUpdates($_SESSION['user_id'];


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results))

      {
//another function to format the activities in a social stream
          echo formatUpdate($row['user_note'],$row['dt'],$row['picture'],$row['username'],$row['id'],$row['reply_id'],$row['reply_name'],$row['votes_up'],$row['votes_down']);


      }
```

i have put the function codes in pastie.

formatUpdate function http://pastie.org/1213958

getUserUpdates function http://pastie.org/1213962

**EDIT** both functions are from different files they are included in home.php,
formatUpdate from functions.php
getUserUpdates from queries.php

Comment: Could you elaborate on what exactly you dislike about your current process? If you cannot concretely identify a problem then there isn't much to fix.

Comment: That's not valid PHP. You can't create a closure/lambda like you're trying to do in that code, and you're missing a parenthesis. Before you tell us it works, test it. ;)

Comment: sorry i missed that, but its working , sorry again, i dont what you mean by lambda/cosure.

Comment: He means the line `$results=function getUserUpdates($_SESSION['user_id'];` will result in a syntax error. The code posted will not parse.

Comment: oh okay kool, sorry i mistypes on stackoverflow, but on my code, the parenthesis is thier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I think you mean:

```
$results = getUserUpdates($_SESSION['user_id']);
```

In your `getUserUpdates()` function there is a redundant branch:

```
if ($username == $_SESSION['u_name']){
    // return something
}

if ($username != $_SESSION['u_name']){
    // return something else
}
```

You don't need the second `if` statement as any code run at that point will only be run if `$username != $_SESSION['u_name']`.

In my opinion, it's usually better not to have different functions directly echoing HTML up the stack (such as `echoVote()`). It's preferred to have functions return data and have the original caller echo it. This allows the caller to perform additional data massaging if desired.

Other than that, your code is fetching data, looping through and acting on the results which is pretty much standard fare.

I think your instinct is to be a little too harsh on yourself ;) There are improvements to be made but it's certainly not the worst way to do anything.

Comment: thank you very much, i understand fully what u said, but i didnt get the one you said about echovote function, shall i remove the function and do the processing inside the formatupdate function! :)),lol im not harsh on myself, but i see  some pretty good code done by other people,  and im a newbie so yeh i get this feeling!!

Comment: plus i need to know the improvements :))) i love perfection

Comment: I only meant that rather than echo html directly from functions, have the function return the html. But don't worry about that now. That's just a preference to keep in mind going forward.

Answer (score 2):

**First** of all, it's good that you have separate functions for getting the data and for formatting the data. It's a good start toward refactoring your code. It makes it easier in the future: if you ever want to format your data differently, you can just expand your formatter.

**Second**, this is what coreyward meant by a lambda:

`$results=function getUserUpdates($_SESSION['user_id'];`

Remove the `function` keyword. You use `function` when you're defining a function. But here you're only calling one. (You defined it in queries.php.)

**Third**, I agree with webbiedave about the echo statements. A good way to avoid that: In the "heart" of your app, collect all the HTML into one place. Then, when you've collected everything you're going to display on the page, you can echo it all at once. This makes it a lot easier to keep track of what you're doing, and to remember the order of everything. It also makes it easier to add headers and footers, or do more formatting. Otherwise, if you have `echo` statements scattered around your code, it's a lot easier to let something slip that shouldn't be there.

Here's a very basic example of what I mean:

```
$html = '';
$results = getUserUpdates($_SESSION['user_id'];

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
    $fields = array(
        'user_note' => $row['user_note'],
        'dt' => $row['dt'],
        'picture' => $row['picture'],
        'username' => $row['username'],
        'id' => $row['id'],
        'reply_id' => $row['reply_id'],
        'reply_name' => $row['reply_name'],
        'votes_up' => $row['votes_up'],
        'votes_down' => $row['votes_down'],
    );
    $html .= formatUpdate($fields);
}
// This way you can do whatever you want to $html here.
echo $html;
```

Also notice that I put all the fields from $row into an array and passed it to formatUpdate(). That has two advantages:

1. It's easier to read.
2. If you ever
       want to change the fields that
       formatUpdate deals with, you don't
       have to worry about searching
       through your code to change the
       arguments every time you call it.

Comment: oh my god thank you so much,that code is so much easier to read and clean, i love my code now ;)), i knew my code was ugly hahah thanks @willel +1 upvote from me